# Failing Azure deployment: Found conflicts

Tags: azure, deployment

I am having a problem deploying a web app to Azure  and am not sure how best to go about troubleshooting it.

I am deploying from a bitbucket repository but it fails with the following message:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5):

warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

Building locally works fine and I have tried clearing out the packages and bin folders but i still get this message.

I have looks about and there seems to be no way of turning on the detailed (or diagnostic) deployment logging mode so i can't discover which libraries are causing the problem.

Has anyone ever come accross this? does anyone have any ideas how best to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out i was building my app to target .NET 4.5.1 rather than 4.6 - changing this seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a full (re-)deployment?
If you are publishing your webapp from Visual Studio, there is an option for this: 
Settings → Advanced Settings → Deployment Update ...→ [ ] If deployment can't be updated do a full deployment.